# Gorm fill struct within a struct with the results not fully working

Tags: go, go-gorm

I do a simple query in Gorm:

```
err := db.Preload("users").
    Where("orders.created_at >= now() - interval 3 day").
    Find(&orders).
    Error
```

I also tried it this way:

```
err := db.Select("orders.*, users.*").
    Where("orders.created_at >= now() - interval 3 day and users.first_name != ''").
    Joins("left join users on users.customer_id = orders.customer_id").
    Find(&orders).
    Error
```

This should fill a "orders" struct which has a "Users Users" struct in it. When I log my query it looks fine, when I copy and paste it into Phpmyadmin it works perfectly, but in Go my struct is empty! well... the "users" part is empty. The orders part is filled correctly. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? my orders struct:

```
type Orders struct {
   CustomerId    int
   Users         Users   `gorm:"foreignKey:customer_id"`
   Method        string
   Amount        float64
   Subtotal      float64
   Total         float64
   Btw           float64
   Status        string
   OrderMailSend int
}
```

and my users struct:

```
type Users struct {
   CustomerId int
   Email      string
   FirstName  string
   LastName   string
}
```

If I use my first query and call it (in Go) I will receive this result:

```
{
    "CustomerId": 211197,
    "Users": {
        "CustomerId": 0,
        "Email": "",
        "FirstName": "",
        "LastName": ""
    },
    "Method": "iDEAL",
    "Amount": 10,
    "Subtotal": 10,
    "Total": 10,
    "Btw": 0,
    "Status": "paid",
    "OrderMailSend": 0
}
```

together with an error: can't preload field users for models.Orders

If I would just copy and paste the query itself in phpmyadmin console and run it, I do get complete results i.e. one order with a user connected to it. So that means the query itself is alright I recon.

In the database the orders table (customer_id) has a foreign key to the users table (customer_id).

Comment: Does the first query work correctly (i.e. is the Users struct filled then)?

Comment: No, I get an error can't preload field users for models.Orders.

Comment: But will this first code get your Users structs filled?

Comment: It will fill the "order" struct but leave the "users" struct within the "order" struct with empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing: Try renaming your Users key field to CustomerID, that's the go way and what gorm seems to like also.

Also, your Order struct does not have a primary key. That may muck things up for gorm.

With this, the first query should work.

The second query will not magically fill the `Users` struct because the `Find` method only scans in the top-level entity.

`Joins` with custom join SQL as you've used does not tell gorm to also scan the extra fields into the sub-entity.

But since this is a one to one relationship, you should be able to use [Joins preloading](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Joins-Preloading) which results in a similar thing to your Preload query, but all in a single database query.

```golang
err := db.
    Joins("Users").
    Where("orders.created_at >= now() - interval 3 day AND users.first_name != ''").
    Find(&orders).
    Error
```

Comment: Also note, that gorm usually names the structs as singular nouns, and tables plural. This won't affect functionality, but makes for more sensible code reading.

Comment: This indeed does work, thank you very much Ezequiel! one last question... my "conditions" are ignored in the preload. I only want to receive "orders" where a user exists i.e. first_name is not null.

err := db.Preload("Users", "first_name IS NOT NULL").Where("orders.created_at >= now() - interval 3 day").Find(&orders).Error

Comment:  Have you tried adding that condition to the Where clause instead? I think Joins preloading doesn't support adding conditions. See what you get with `Where("orders.created_at >= now() - interval 3 day AND users.first_name IS NOT NULL")`